# Have an SVG and let d3.js manage it

Tags: svg, d3.js, inkscape

Is it possible to do the chart or visualization as SVG in Inkscape and then let d3.js update it with correct data dynamically? Like drawing bars and changing digits according to some JSON.

I am not yet started with `d3.js`, and I am afraid that it can only produce SVG itself and won't be able to handle complex drawings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is tutorial for using Inkscape with d3.js - http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/d3_inkscape/